# Text classification for more than 2 classes with python and keras

Tags: python, keras, text-classification

I'm trying categorization with a neuronal network.

my data looks like this:

| Sentence | category |
| --- | --- |
| sentence 1 | 0 |
| sentence 2 | 1 |
| sentence 3 | 2 |
| sentence 4 | 3 |

therefore I have 4 different categories.
I seperate the sentences and the labels in 2 different lists and put the first list (with the sencenes) in a tokenizer.

**Edit:** Because someone asked about data samples. Here is a link to the Dropbox ([data_samples.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4vog17etmot06y/data_samples.txt?dl=0)) and some more explanations. 0 = not needed, 1 = title, 2= name from author, 3 = pages. The sentence is with | from the label separated. There are lot of special character (like -- > ,") because of the lemmatization but the tokenizer skips these characters.
The content is from different websites and I only use it in the context of study (no for money or in bad intentions)

```
y_train = array(labels) # it has to be numpy array otherwise it will cause errors, labels is a list of integers
x_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(newLines) # newLines is a list with all sentences
x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=sequenceLength)
vocabSize = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

An now i will train my model

```
mymodel = Sequential()
mymodel.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocabSize, output_dim=100, input_length=sequenceLength))
mymodel.add(Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
mymodel.add(MaxPooling1D())
mymodel.add(Flatten())
mymodel.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
mymodel.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
mymodel.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = mymodel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=8)
```

But if i start the programm i get the following error:

- ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible

I know it is because of the last Dense Layer. If I write 1 instead of 4, I don't get an error. But I thought the last dense layer need a 4 as a parameter, because I have 4 categories.
I think the last dense layer with a 1 instead of a 4 is not correct, because loss is 0.0000e+00. And that look not correct xD

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you also share 1 or 2 sample records of x_train and y_train data ?

Comment: @sam ok. I edited the question with a dropbox link. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace loss="categorical_crossentropy" with "sparse_ categorical_crossentropy".

The model produces a value per class; the sparse_ loss knows how to compare a single value in range [0-3] to these 4 score values.

Comment: thanks man. :D This fixed my problem.
once again the solution was relatively simple. But you can't see the forest for the trees. xD
And my accuracy went right up to 99%